# Non-invocable member 'TSM.ProxMatchOutputContract.DataField' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method

I've been looking around at some of the responses to this error, but I haven't figured it out.

Here is my declaration:

```
   private IEnumerable<string> _dataFields = null;
    [DataMember(Name = "data_fields")]
    public IEnumerable<string> DataFields
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dataFields == null)
            {
                _dataFields = new List<string>();
            }
            return _dataFields;
        }
        set { _dataFields = value; }
    }
```

Here is where I am using Datafields and getting my error which is being thrown at ExpectedDataFields(index) and also result.DataFields(index):

```
     internal void OnDeserializedPopulateQueryResults(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (this.ExpectedDataFields.Count() > 0 && this.QueryResults.Count() > 0)
        {

            foreach (ProxMatchOutputContract result in this.QueryResults)
            {
                for (int index = 0; index <= (int)result.DataFields.Count() - 1; index++)

                {
                    *result.DataField[this.ExpectedDataFields(index)] = result.DataFields(index);*

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
result.DataField[this.ExpectedDataFields(index)]
```

attempts to treat DataField as if it had an indexer, which `IEnumerable<string>` does not.

Perhaps change the definition of your property to something that does have an indexer, like `List<string>`.

Also, I assume that the asterisks around that line are a typo, or perhaps an attempt to format the line italic (which does not work when the line is already formatted as code).

Comment: Nevermind, that didn't seem to solve the problem.  I changed to

`                public List<string> ExpectedDataFields

        {
            get
            {
                if (_expectedDataFields == null)
                {
                    _expectedDataFields = new List<string>();
                }
                return _expectedDataFields;
            }
            set { _expectedDataFields = value; }
        }
`